# Does Pentaho Kettle create dimension and fact tables

Tags: pentaho, dimensional-modeling

I am new to pentaho kettle and wanted to know that does it create data warehouse and dimension and fact tables automatically?

Can anyone provide me a link from where i can study the entire features of kettle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the Docs?

[Kettle Documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Latest+Pentaho+Data+Integration+%28aka+Kettle%29+Documentation)

Specifically, look at the `Combination Lookup/Update` step and the `Dimension Lookup/Update` step.

Any other questions, check here or on the Pentaho forums.